# Angular - Writing Integration Tests for a component referencing child component via @ViewChild

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have to write the test case where it is calling the function within the function.

1. this is the main component of which I want to write test case. Want to write a unit test for `openModel` function.

```js
@ViewChild(SecondComponent) public secondComponent: SecondComponent;

openModal() {
  this.secondComponent.showModal();
}
```

2. This is the second component which has `showModal` function.

```js
@ViewChild(ModalComponent) public modalComponent: ModalComponent;

public showModal() {
  this.modalComponent.showModal();
}
```

3. This is my attempted test case so far.

```js
it(
  'should open drop modal', () => {
    const showModalSpy = spyOn(SecondComponent, 'showModal').and.callThrough();
    component.openModal();
    expect(showModalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
);
```

Comment: **component** is a testbed component?

Comment: No, it the main component which i want to test

Comment: Read https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component This is a guide for testing a component. You can mock your modules,  components and service. Also can inject your services in an *it*. For example `fixture.detectChanges();` detect changes on your test component so you can see if your modal has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you really want to do here is to write the Integration Test for your `MainComponent`'s `openModal`. So you should ask yourself, what is this method doing?

**Rule of Thumb for writing Automation Tests:**
You should always focus on testing what the **unit(`MainComponent` in this case)** is doing. Everything else(`SecondComponent`) in this case, can be mocked.

Now to answer the question you'll ask yourself while writing the test is, the `openModal` method is calling a function named `showModal` on the `secondComponent` property that you have on your `MainComponent`.

So according to our Rule of Thumb, we'll mock the `showModal` method on the `secondComponent` that we can get from the `fixture`'s `componentInstance` property.

And so, your Integration Tests for this should look like the following:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './../modal/modal.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './../second/second.component';

describe('MainComponent', () => {
  let component: MainComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MainComponent, ModalComponent, SecondComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('openModal', () => {

    it('should call the `showModal` method on the `secondComponent` property we have on our component', () => {
      // Arrange
      let secondComponent = component.secondComponent;
      let spy = spyOn(secondComponent, 'showModal');

      // Act
      component.openModal();
  
      // Assert
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });

  });

});
```

Hope this helps!